# What is the name of this function? index?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, definition

> Burton- Number theory p.163
>
> Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.
>
> Let $r$ be a primitive root mod $n$, so that $<r>=\mathbb{Z}_n^*$
>
> Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$
>
> Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $a=r^k$
>
> Then, $k$ is called the index of $a$ relative to $r$ and denoted by $ind_r(a)$.

Well.. this definition can be extended to any cyclic group and since the term "index" is really ambiguous, if this tool is useful, I am sure that there is another terminology for "index" here.

Is there another name for "index" here?

This is not on wikipedia so I think this term is not standard..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's referred to as the discrete logarithm of $a$ with respect to $r$, denoted by
$$k = \log_r a \pmod{\varphi(n)}$$
Where $\varphi(n)$ is the euler totient function wich counts the elements of $\mathbb Z_n^\ast$.

Comment: if  $Z_n*$ is not cyclic then do we have $k=\log_ra(\bmod\lambda(n))$ which is Carmicheal function if order of $r$ is $\lambda(n)$?